# cual es la diferencia entre ActiveRoute, Route y Router en angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, component, router

como van? hay algo que me confunde mucho y es el sistema de routing en angular, me podrian explicar cuales son las diferencias entre ActiveRoute, Route y Router en angular,
Espero logren ayudarme, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que ActivatedRoute se puede reutilizar , ActivatedRouteSnapshotes un objeto inmutable que representa una versión particular de ActivatedRoute. Expone todas las mismas propiedades que los ActivatedRoutevalores simples, mientras que las ActivatedRouteexpone como observables.

Aquí está el comentario en la implementación:

```
export class ActivatedRoute {
     /** The current snapshot of this route */
     snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
```

Si un enrutador reutiliza un componente y no crea una nueva ruta activada, tendrá dos versiones de ActivatedRouteSnapshotla misma ActivatedRoute. Suponga que tiene la siguiente configuración de enrutamiento:

```
path: /segment1/:id,
component: AComponent
```

Ahora navega a:

```
/segment1/1
```

Tendrá el parámetro en el as .activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id1

Ahora navega a:

```
/segment1/2
```

endrá el parámetro en el as .activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id2

Puede verlo implementando lo siguiente:

`````
export class AComponent {
     constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) {    
       r.url.subscribe((u) => {
         console.log(r.snapshot.params.id);
       });
````
`````

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Javier

Comment: de nada espero haberte ayudado